# Is their some kind of device that can take a picture to locate where these leaks are located?

Tags: leaks

Our house is a 4 level split model and within the guest room which is on the 2nd level (level above the basement) I hear a drips somewhere above the ceiling.    These drip sounds are located in 2 different locations above the ceiling.

Is their some kind of device that can take a picture to locate where these leaks are located so that we don't have to tear up the house to find the source of these leaks?

Comment: What kind on construction? If its open web truss you can sometimes pull a ceiling fixture to see what's going on.

Comment: Odds are excellent that you'll need to do some ceiling ripping to actually FIX the leaks, so listen carefully (perhaps use  stethoscope to pinpoint the leak) and cut a hole and look. I have come to strongly prefer arrangements where utilities are routed in accessible space, or provided with access panels, rather than buried in drywall that has to be ripped to fix anything, but the latter is all too common, and you simply have to face up to the drywall repair. On the plus side, lots of drywall repair is barely harder than a little drywall repair.

Answer (score 2):

An infrared camera might be your best bet. They're quite expensive, but you might be able to find a place locally to rent one. You might also be able to find a local plumber or HVAC company that has one, and would be willing to come out and take a look for you. It might be worth it to pay a bit extra, to have somebody who knows how to use the equipment help you.

Comment: They're not all "quite expensive", some are just "expensive".  [There's an app for that](http://www.flir.com/flirone/content/?id=69369).  I also heard that larger Home Depot stores were going to add FLIR cameras to their Tool Rental center.  But I agree with professional help - tools are only as good as the experience of the person holding them.